# Getting rows in the same table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get rows in a Table.

Imagine I got two records (t1 and t2). I want to get rows that do not have the t1.start_hour BETWEEN t2.start_hour and t2.finish_hour. I basically want only to get the occurrences that don not have conflict in hours with another one.

This is the table:

```
create_table "occurrences", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "start_hour"
    t.string   "finish_hour"
    t.date     "start_date"
    t.date     "finish_date"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
    t.integer  "activity_id"
  end
```

And this is the SQL query I came up so far:

```
Occurrence.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM occurrences t1 INNER JOIN occurrences t2 ON (t1.start_hour NOT BETWEEN t2.start_hour and t2.finish_hour)")
```

It gives me duplicate results. I'm not be able to remove them and get the correct answer.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Example

INPUT

```
#<Occurrence id: 1, start_hour: "19:00", finish_hour: "20:20", start_date: "2012-05-30", finish_date: "2012-05-30", created_at: "2012-05-30 09:58:19", updated_at: "2012-05-30 09:58:19", activity_id: 1>, 

#<Occurrence id: 2, start_hour: "19:30", finish_hour: "20:10", start_date: "2012-05-30", finish_date: "2012-05-30", created_at: "2012-05-30 09:58:19", updated_at: "2012-05-30 09:58:19", activity_id: 2>,

#<Occurrence id: 3, start_hour: "22:00", finish_hour: "23:20", start_date: "2012-05-30", finish_date: "2012-05-30", created_at: "2012-05-30 09:58:20", updated_at: "2012-05-30 09:58:20", activity_id: 3>
```

OUTPUT

```
#<Occurrence id: 1, start_hour: "19:00", finish_hour: "20:20", start_date: "2012-05-30", finish_date: "2012-05-30", created_at: "2012-05-30 09:58:19", updated_at: "2012-05-30 09:58:19", activity_id: 1>, 

#<Occurrence id: 3, start_hour: "22:00", finish_hour: "23:20", start_date: "2012-05-30", finish_date: "2012-05-30", created_at: "2012-05-30 09:58:20", updated_at: "2012-05-30 09:58:20", activity_id: 3>
```

The record with the start_hour = 19:30 does not output because is between 19:00 and 20:20 of  another one.

EDIT:

I Got the solution:

```
Occurrence.find_by_sql("SELECT start_hour FROM occurrences WHERE start_hour NOT IN (SELECT t2.start_hour FROM occurrences t1 INNER JOIN occurrences t2 ON ((t1.activity_id <> t2.activity_id AND t2.start_hour BETWEEN t1.start_hour and t1.finish_hour)))")
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are trying to achieve here. It would be better if you can provide us more details about the real-world problem you are trying to solve by this.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume there are 3 records in table. (I am taking integer in place of datatime as this will be easier)

```
  id     start    end
   1      1        3
   2      4        5
   3      7        9
```

When I will try to find the rows were start is not in between start and end, than for id =1 both first row will be true and will come in result. Similarly for row with id =2 (start=4) both rows will qualify (making third row come twice in result) Same will happen for third row and you will end up with six rows.

Its not very clear what you are trying to achieve here, but putting distinct will remove the duplicate.

EDIT: You might consider putting inner joins on start and finish date.

Answer (score 0):

not tested (from memory) 
you need to exlude the record itself --> t1.activity_id <> t2.activity_id 
left join or you won't get the good ones
where there is no right side

would need to test this :p

```
SELECT * FROM occurrences t1 
left JOIN occurrences t2 
ON (t1.activity_id <> t2.activity_id and t1.start_hour BETWEEN t2.start_hour and t2.finish_hour)
where t2.activity_id is null
```

Comment: The result is two records with all fields with nil value.

EDIT: The number os records is correct.